# Subtraction/Addition from seperate rows/columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Day    Diff
137    0
185    48
249    64
139   -110
```

In the column `Diff` whenever a negative value is encountered I want to subtract 365 from the value in `Day` from the previous row and then add that value to the `Day` value in the current row of the negative number.  For example, in this scenario when `-110` is encountered I want to do 365-249 (249 is from `Day` in previous row) and then add 139. So 365-249 = 116 and 116 + 139 = 255.  Therefore `-110` would be replaced with `255`.

My desired output then is:

```
Day    Diff
137    0
185    48
249    64
139    255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [32]: df.loc[df.Diff < 0, 'Diff'] = 365 + df.Day - df.shift().loc[df.Diff < 0, 'Day']

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
   Day   Diff
0  137    0.0
1  185   48.0
2  249   64.0
3  139  255.0
```